# Pentaho Community Edition Directory Struture, Plugins Integration and MySQL Connection

Tags: java, mysql, pentaho

I am working on Pentaho  Community Edition in the Windows Environment and downloaded the latest Pentaho BI Server File from Sourceforge.net.(file name biserver-ce-4.5.0-stable.zip) and extacted it to C:\Program Files\Pentaho 
 so that my directory structure becomes

> C:\
>
> ```
>   | 
>    -----Program Files  
>
>          |----------administration-console
>
>          |----------biserver-ce
> ```

Now what i am doing for running the PUC and PAC is firt start the tomcat from the bat file located at

> C:\Program Files\Pentaho\biserver-ce\tomcat\bin\startup.bat

After tomcat has started i start the BI server from the file

> C:\Program Files\Pentaho\biserver-ce\start-pentaho.bat

and finally the Administrative Console from

> C:\Program Files\Pentaho\administration-console\start-pac.bat

The first Question is that What i am doing is correct or not.

Secondly i have seen in tutorials that the admin panel Left Menu contains options as Home, Administration, Status, Configuration, Utilities etc but on my side i have just two options in the Admin Console, Home and Administration. How can i add/include those other options.

Third Question is i have downloaded `Pentaho Data Integration-CE-4.3.0` and `Pentaho Report Design -CE-3.9.0-GA` file but how do i place them in the Current Pentaho Directory structure to access them.

Fourth Question is how can i connect the Pentaho BI server to databases that i have in my local system accessible through MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) That is correct, but it won't run if you haven't configured databases for your users/hibernate

2) The version they are using is the Enterprise Edition, the one you have is the Community Edition

3) You do not have to place them in your Pentaho directory structure since they are external tools. In order to use them, you have to use them in `*.xaction` files or publish the `KTR/KJB` and `PRPT`s to the BI Server.

4) You need to run the scripts in your local database. The scripts are located in `biserver-ce/data`